# Can you program an app for android to be fully customized or does it have to look like material design?

Tags: android

I designed the graphic interface of an app and now I want to bring it to live on Android. I have never programmed an app based on my design, just learnt de basics following material design styles.
Will it be possible for me to make it look 100% like my design that I created from scratch disregarding material design, or will it have to be a Frankenstein between my design and Android's material design? Also, can I achieve my goal by using Android Studio or should I try React Native or others?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can look however you want it to look.

If you are struggling to get it to look how you want with Android Studio, but have knowledge of html+css, then giving React Native a go might be easier for you to fully customize it.

Just be aware that it is recommended to follow the guidelines at least a bit, especially in regards to locations of common buttons etc as users can get used to how apps 'work', and going against the flow with a completely new user-flow can sometimes make it harder to use, as it doesn't follow their expectations.